# laravel 5.0.* - make:command MyCom создается в app/Commands а не в app/Console/Commands

Tags: laravel, artisan

laravel 5.0.* make:command MyCom создается в app/Commands, а не в app/Console/Commands.

Собственно вопрос у меня почему так, сразу после установки, ничего не менял.

Ну и соответственно команда не работает, пишет не найдено в пространстве имен.

Содержимое созданного файла

```
<?php namespace App\Commands;

use App\Commands\Command;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\SelfHandling;

class Data extends Command implements SelfHandling {

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Execute the command.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function handle()
    {
        //
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данные симптомы вызваны ошибкой при создании нового проекта, происходящей из за конфликта имен в phpparser и php7. Решением проблемы является обновление phpparser'a и создание проекта заново.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install php-parser
```